# Find generating function: summation from $0$ to infinity of $i(5^i)$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I know the generating function of the summation from $0$ to infinity of $nx^n$ is $= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

So would this be something like $\frac{5}{(1-5)^2}$?

Comment: There has to be a variable in a generating function.

Comment: Where does the variable come from then?

Comment: For the given series, the variable keeps track of the terms. Example since $1/(1-x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots $ it generates the sequence of all $1$'s. The coefficient of $x^n$ is the $n$th term.